# what to do if there are no errors in the code but application does not run on the emulator?

Tags: android, exception, android-intent, android-logcat

I am developing a very simple android app with activities and intents.There are no errors in the code.

Console shows:

```
[2013-06-04 15:21:38 - Shoppapp] Android Launch!
[2013-06-04 15:21:38 - Shoppapp] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-04 15:21:38 - Shoppapp] Performing com.example.shoppapp.MainActivity activity
```

Launch:

```
[2013-06-04 15:21:48 - Shoppapp] Uploading Shoppapp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-04 15:21:53 - Shoppapp] Installing Shoppapp.apk...
[2013-06-04 15:22:49 - Shoppapp] Success!
[2013-06-04 15:22:50 - Shoppapp] Starting activity com.example.shoppapp.MainActivity on
```

Device emulator-5554

When I open the app in the emulator a blank screen appears and then it closes with the message

> Unfortunately your app has stopped working and app closes

`Logcat` shows the following exceptions:

```
06-04 09:53:46.665: E/Trace(2880): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-04 09:53:49.125: D/AndroidRuntime(2880): Shutting down VM
06-04 09:53:49.125: W/dalvikvm(2880): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-04 09:53:49.557: D/dalvikvm(2880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 72K, 7% free 2710K/2904K, paused 251ms+42ms, total 419ms
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shoppapp/com.example.shoppapp.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.shoppapp.WELCOME }
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.shoppapp.WELCOME }
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at com.example.shoppapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-04 09:53:49.595: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     ... 11 more
06-04 09:53:59.676: I/Process(2880): Sending signal. PID: 2880 SIG: 9
06-04 10:04:41.595: D/AndroidRuntime(3074): Shutting down VM
06-04 10:04:41.608: W/dalvikvm(3074): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
```

Comment: The exception is clearly self-explaining: "Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.shoppapp.WELCOME }" You didn't declare activity in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

Did you declared your **WELCOME** activity your Manifest file

It shows  ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent `com.example.shoppapp.WELCOME`